# Go nested struct

Tags: go, struct

How do I create a Go struct something like this,

```
{Name:Test { App1:Version1 App2:Version2}}
```

using Go where `App1/2` and `Version1/2` is dynamic.

I have tried the follwing,

```
type Final struct {
        App string `json:"Name"`
        Applications [] Application
}
type final []Final
type Application struct {
         App string `json:`
}

final := Final {
        Name:"Test",
        Applications: []Application{
                {GetApps()},
        },
        }
```

where GetApps will return a list of App details, instead I would like to have a key value pair where key would be the Appname and value would be its details. I just need a syntax, kindly help

Comment: You can't. Go uses static types. You _could_ use a map instead, if being dynamic is a requirement.

Comment: you can't use structure if you want dynamic types to be created. All you can do is use interface to assign values to dynamic keys created inside interface

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, using a `map` for `Final`'s `Applications` is likely what you are after.

```
type Final struct {
    Name         string `json:"Name"`
    Applications map[string]string
}
```

Then you can assign it as in your attempts:

```
final := Final{
    Name: "Test",
    Applications: GetApps(),
}
```

Make sure `GetApps()` returns a `map[string]string` and you will have your dynamic keys when json marshalling.

See [an example here](https://play.golang.org/p/FLMVrZEbal6).

Comment: Another way you could go is to enhance your original `Application` struct to include a `Version string` element. Though the end result would be slightly different: `"Applications":{{"App":"App1", "Version":"Version1"},{"App":"App2", "Version":"Version2"}}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need anything to be dynamic. This refactor seems to cover your case:

```
  type Application {
          Name string
          Detail string
  }

  type Final struct {
          Name string
          Applications []Application
  }

  func GetApps() []Application {
          // ... Get a slice of Applications
          return []Application{}
  }

  func main() {
          final := Final{
                  Name: "Test",
                   Applications: []Application{}
          }

          for _, app := range GetApps() {
                   final.Applications = append(final.Applications, app)
          }

          // final is ready
  }
```

Type `Application` could also be a `map[string]string` like other have mentioned or a struct it doesn't matter because the type is known at compile time and there is no need for dynamic type here.